# How to ensure that jasmine's expect() was executed in test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have such test for angular app:

```
it("should return false if all products loaded", function () {
    $httpBackend.flush();
    scope.loadNextProducts(15).then(function (isThereMoreToLoad) {
        expect(isThereMoreToLoad).toBe(false);
    });
    scope.$apply();
});
```

If i forget to write ether `$httpBackend.flush();` or `scope.$apply();` test will never reach `expect()` part and test will be successful.

Is there way to ensure that jasmine test executed expect(), and if not then it should fail?

Something like specifying to `it()` how many `expect()` to expect, or tell jasmine that each test should execute at least one `expect()` otherwise it should fail.

Comment: Sure. Check this out: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

Comment: Yep this looks interesting, but as i understood this is mechanism to set timeout on a async tests, and if timeout is reached then test fails. I have promises here and i should somehow wrap it in waitsFor? Could work, but this further destroys my tests as now they becomes several level of nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
```

That should, well, verify that your tests have no expectations that have not been visited and it should also verify that all of your expected server calls have been called.

You can find more info on the [Angular $backend docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)

Comment: As i understand this would deal with parts "If i forget to write $httpBackend.flush();". What about part or "If i forget to write scope.$apply();"?